# DevExpress RepositoryItemComboBox different background color

Tags: combobox, devexpress, color-scheme

Does it possible to set different background color to each item of DevExpress RepositoryItemComboBox?
RepositoryItemComboBox.AppearanceDropDown.BackColor affects all items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the RepositoryItem's [DrawItem](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemComboBox_DrawItemtopic) event.  Here is some sample code:

```
private void repositoryItemComboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, ListBoxDrawItemEventArgs e) {
            if(e.State == DrawItemState.None) {
                e.Appearance.BackColor = e.Index % 2 == 0 ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
            }
        }
```